# Edit Total on Profile Not Matching Up

Tags: support, badges, suggested-edits

According to my profile I have 132 suggested edits.

According to my progress towards Strunk & White on the [review](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/) page, I have edited 79 posts.

Why don't these numbers match up. Is this my fault or the sites's?

Answer (score 4):

According to [your profile](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/34364/jae?tab=activity), you only have 93 suggested edits:

> [image: Jae's Profile]

A number of those were also rejected, which would get you to the 79 edits listed on the Review page.

For the future, also keep in mind that not every edit [counts towards the editor badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges):

> - does not include edits to your own posts
> - does not include edits to tags
> - community-wiki posts are eligible
> - tag wiki posts are eligible
>
> To count for S&W/Copy Editor, the edit must cover the title, the body or both.